# magento track event before payment made successfully

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, payment

I want to reject payment if some condition is false using event observer. For this what i have to do?

And which observer event i have to use.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Edit this question for the first one and use the [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button to ask another.

Comment: k i asked single question

Answer (score 1):

You can fire this event `sales_order_payment_capture` and write your condition inside Observer.php

You can also find all the event list from here [events](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/)